# Is it haram to draw a eye, but no face or body

Tags: halal-haram, drawing

Salam, I have gotten into the habit of drawing eyes, and I don't know if it is permissable in Islam. Can someone please explain to me if it is allowed or no?

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @EPIC Tube HD:  About taswir, as far as I know when it is haraam is when the form is complete, in a way that it the statue or picture is being given ruh, it can live normally. So, when it is a single head, or a particular body part, or something like that, it is still allowed. Because when a ruh is being put inside, it cannot live normally. – EPIC Tube HD

In one narration, Aisyah had a sheet (or was it a pillow I forgot) with a picture of a pigeon. When Rasulullah saw it, He cut that picture and leave other part of the picture still intact. In a separate occasion, he found a full statue in front of an entrance of a house. He then ordered that statue to be destroyed, or leave just some part of it in such way that it doesn't resemblance a living being anymore. And there is an acception to this ruling. Taswir is allowed for toys. It was narrated by Aisyah RA. – EPIC Tube HD